# How to set array values to a constructor c#

Tags: c#, arrays, constructor

I got the program running guys thanks alot i just deleted everything and started again from scratch! Now I am having problems with :

// The constructor

```
public Grade ( string cname , int Studentident , int [] homework , int [] classwork ,      int [] midexam , int [] finalexam)
{
    coursename = cname ;
    Studentid = Studentident ;  
    hwgrade = homework ;
    cwgrade = classwork ;
    midegrade = midexam ;
    finalegrade = finalexam ;
}
```

// trying to set the values

```
Grade grade = new Grade('m',1,1,1,1,1);
```

it is giving me an error cannot convert from int to int[]

Comment: What are you wanting to accept? Do you need an array of integers for `homework`, `classwork`, `midexam`, and `finalexam`?

Comment: if you can't spend the 15 seconds it takes to understand that error message, you aren't going to have a very good time in C#...

Comment: You should understand such small errors just by looking at the error message..or you should try google or expect downvote here..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You must pass in *arrays*, not single values:

```
Grade grade = new Grade('m',
                        new int[] {1}, 
                        new int[] {1}, 
                        new int[] {1}, 
                        new int[] {1}, 
                        new int[] {1});
```

`int` is not the same as `int[]`, after all.

The above assumes that your fields (such as `hwgrade`) are declared as `int[]` and not `int`.

If this is not the case, and the fields are actually integers and not integer arrays, you need to change the method signature to take integers instead of arrays:

```
public Grade(string cname, 
             int Studentident, 
             int homework, 
             int classwork,
             int midexam,
             int finalexam)
```

Comment: They are actually integer arrays. Thanks alot Oded your method allowed me to get rid of the errors

Comment: @Shane - Glad I could help, but I can't help wonder if you understand now why you got the error and why my answer helped...

Comment: Well for the most part I understand that int's are different than int arrays. Since i declared some of them as int arrays I would have to use the proper syntax in order to set values to them. But my main goal is to get more values added to the arrays by the user entering them (Console.ReadLine()) but I am not sure if this is possible

Comment: Thanks again, This is all mind blowing , still trying to understand why use constructors over just a simple input member function

Comment: @Shane - Using a constructor allows you to place initialization logic in one place.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace with this code - delete [] if you wish use int, and not array of int

```
Grade ( string cname , int Studentident , int homework , int classwork ,      int midexam , int  finalexam)
{
  ...
}
```

Or create array with `new int[] {1}` and pass in parameters